# Error 404 : Spring MVC and Hibernate due to Hibernate Mapping

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Getting ERROR:404 due to the hibernate mapping in the applicationContext.xml. But unable to find the solution for it.

I have a new Type that is image.

Image.java

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class Image
{
    private String image_size;
    private String image_type;
    private MultipartFile image_file;
    private String image_file_url;
    private String image_status;
    <!-- Getters and Setters -->
}
```

The following is the code in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="imageSessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <value>xxx/xxx/xxx/bean/Image.hbm.xml</value>
    </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="imageHibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="imageSessionFactoryBean"></property>
</bean>
```

By only changing the value attribute in the mappingResources property of bean imageSessionFactoryBean I get to see the application working otherwise it shows ERROR:404.
I think the reason can be the name of the File(Image.java) but I'm not sure about this.
Also the Image.hbm.xml contains the mapping of the class Image.java to the database table image.

Image.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Nov 8, 2012 9:26:27 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.Image" table="image">
        <id name="img_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="IMG_ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="content_uid" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="CONTENT_UID" />
    </property>
    <property name="img_url" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="IMG_URL" />
    </property>
    <property name="image_type_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="IMAGE_TYPE_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="image_size_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="IMAGE_SIZE_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="status" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="STATUS" />
    </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: *By only changing the value attribute in the mappingResources I get to see the applicatin working*: then what's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: As soon as I change
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
<property name="mappingResources">
   <value>xxx/xxx/xxx/bean/Image.hbm.xml</value>
</property>
value attribute.
The application works

Comment: Did I made it clear...?? @JBNizet

Comment: Image.hbm.xml file contains the hibernate mapping for the Image.java pojo.
As soon as I change the address to another hibernate mapping file Image_Size_type.hbm.xml(which is the hibernate mapping file for Image_Size_Type.java pojo) the application works i.e I can run the application without a 404 ERROR but that is logically wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to make class `Image` an Hibernate Entity in order to store it in the database.

This will not work, because of its field `private MultipartFile image_file;`. I highly doubt that you can store this field with hibernate. So instead of having this filed, replace it with an byte array. And Populate this byte array with the content of the Multipart file.

```
public class Image
{
    //some primary key required.
    private int id;        

    private String image_size;
    private String image_type;
    private byte[] image_content;
    private String image_file_url;
    private String image_status;
    // Getters and Setters

    //Constructor without parameter required.
    public Image() {}        

    public void applyImgContent(MultipartFile upload) {
         this.image_conten = upload.getBytes();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ralph. But you are wrong with this. I already found my mistake it was just that I did not included a field that was present in the database but was not in my Image.java pojo file due to which the hibernate mapping to that class returned with some errors and as a result I got error 404 due to the hierarchy reaching the applicationContext.xml(Spring config file).

Comment: @HVT7: could you please remove the accept mark, so that I can delete my answer (this is not possible when it is the accepted answer)